# How do you get a note block with an NBT tag so when I place it or /setblock it, it will have a specified note or instrument

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making note block songs and I want an easy way to set the notes on note blocks. How can I set a note block’s instrument or note in my `/setblock` command?

Answer (score 2):

The instrument and note are stored in the note block’s block states. Block states go in the `[]`s that follow the block ID.

Here is a working command:

```
/setblock X Y Z minecraft:note_block[note=7]
```

Visit the Minecraft Wiki page on [note blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Note_block) and scroll down to the Data Values section for a list of accepted values.

Because block states cannot be set in items, it means that you can only use `/setblock` to place the block. You can't use `/give` to get a note block with pre-filled notes and instruments.

Instruments can *theoretically* be set in block states, but Minecraft will automatically update the instrument to match the block below as soon as you try to place the block.

Comment: Also note that it will probably change to the instrument fitting to the block its on as soon as it gets a block update.

Comment: @FabianRöling Tested in 1.16.2. The `instrument` block state updates to the correct instrument immediately after placement, even without a block update. Attempting to use `/setblock` to force the block state to change returns an error: `Could not set the block`

Comment: Oh, I confused "note" and "instrument". I just get the regular instrument instead of the one I type when I use `/setblock ~ ~ ~ note_block[instrument=banjo]`. What did you do to get that error?

Comment: @FabianRöling Use `/setblock ~ ~ ~ note_block[instrument=banjo]`. Then, stand on the note block and type `/setblock ~ ~-1 ~ note_block[instrument=banjo]`.